# User mode setting

Tags: community

here in my developer edition I created one user,now I want to run one program in that user mode. what can i do? Now if,I run any visual force page in user login id it will show "You do not have sufficient privileges to access the controller:test"
could please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give access to Visualforce page to that User's Profile by going to settings--> Customize-->Develop-->Pages-->Click on Security next to Vf page and enable users profile